# Error removing temp files in jdee_flycheck

Tags: emacs, flycheck, jdee

I'm triyg to configure a project with projectile, Jdee and flycheck.
I have customized flycheck-check-syntax-automatically to just check the buffer when it is saved. But when I save, this error is showed:

error in process filter: Removing directory: Permission denied, c:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/JDEE_flycheck_13016Htm

That folder seems to be locked by jdee-server. Any clue?

Comment: did you find the solution? this could work for you https://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee/issues/129

Comment: Thankyou for the link. I am the author of the first response :D.